# 95 Chevy Monte Carlo LS 3.1 idling high in park

Tags: chevrolet, idle, monte-carlo

Upon cranking, car immediately shoots to 3000rpm and hold. Only drops down after I put the car in gear. Even then, pressing the accelerator the car tends to stall sometimes, as if its flooding itself out. After about 10min of driving, it seems to even itself out.  New TPM, IAC, MAP SENSOR, FUEL FILTER, PLUGS & WIRES. Any assistance with this issue will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like an air intake leak to me.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!